# es2015: converting to es2015 with arrow function

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Consider I have this:

```
mongoose.connection.on('error', function (err) {
  if (err) {
    throw err;
  }
});
```

How do I convert this to ES2015 syntax?

I tried:

```
export class MongooseConnectionUtil extends MongooseUtil {
  constructor(...args) {
    super(...args);
    this.connection = mongoose.connection;
  }

  on('error', err) => err {
      if (err) {
        throw err;
      } 
  }
```

also tried with the ()

```
  on('error', ()) => err {
    if (err) {
      throw err;
    }
  }
```

Comment: I don't understand. What's up with the class? Just write `mongoose.connection.on('error', err => { ... })`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mongoose.connection.on` takes two arguments, the event type as a string, and a function. To convert to the arrow function syntax, `func(arg) { ... }` should become `(arg) => { ... }`.

For example, you want to create the error handler when a `MongooseConnectionUtil` instance is created, append your constructor with

```
this.connection.on('error', (err) => {
  if (err) {
    throw err;
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks. What's `this` for?

Comment: In your constructor, `this` references the instance that is being created. Because you assign `this.connection` your question, I have used it in my example.

Comment: Should be able to use: `this.connection.on('error', err => if (err) throw err);`.